# What is "won't" a contraction of?

Tags: etymology, history, contractions, pronunciation-vs-spelling

"Don't", "wouldn't", "couldn't" and "isn't" are all contractions of "do not", "would not", "could not" and "is not"... So what's "won't" a contraction of?

It appears to be "will not", but if so, why isn't it "**willn't**"? (And if there's no good reason, has it *ever* been "willn't" at any point in history?)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/won%27t):

> Abbreviation of *wollnot* or *woll* + *not*, negations of archaic form of *will*.

The Concise Oxford Dictionary of English Etymology agrees:

> XVII. contr. of *wonnot*, assim. of *wol not*

As to other forms, Etymonline [only mentions *wynnot*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=won%27t&searchmode=none):

> first recorded mid-15c. as *wynnot*, later *wonnot* (1580s) before the modern form [*won't*] emerged 1660s.

Comment: Great answer! Now I have one less thing bugging me when I can't sleep :)

Comment: If only they taught this stuff in schools.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: They do if you take German.

Answer (score 42):

*Won’t* actually has a pretty interesting and complex history. Ultimately it does come from a contraction of *will* and *not*, but it all happened in a rather roundabout way.

It all started off with the Old English verb *willan/wyllan*, meaning *to will*, *wish*, or *want*. Even in Old English it was used occasionally to denote a future intent. “Ic wille gan” could mean “I want to go” or “I will go”, depending on context.

Now, the thing about negatives in Old English is that they were often reduced:

> *na(w)ðer* = *nahwæðer* = *ne* + *hwæðer*
> *neither* = *not* + *whether*
>
> *næfre* = *ne* + *æfre*
> *never* = *not* + *ever*
>
> *nabbað* = *ne* + *habbað*
> *haven’t* = *have* + *not*
>
> We nabbað naðor ne hlaf ne wæter.
> We have neither bread nor water.

*Not* comes from *naht* via *noht*. Related to *nawiht* meaning *naught*, it originally meant *in no way*, but came to be used as an emphatic form of *ne*. Subsequently it became unstressed and supplanted *ne* altogether. This is an example of [Jespersen’s Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen%27s_Cycle).

All these things combined led to a new negative form of *willan*, *wynnot*. The past forms of *willan* began with *wold-*, which is where we get *would*. Under the influence of these forms and the related verb *wol*, *wynnot* became *wonnot* by the late 1500s.

Finally, the modern form *won’t* emerged by the 1660s as a result of reducing the final vowel in *wonnot*. It appears to be the first word so contracted; most of the other *-n’t* contractions we use today (*can’t*, *couldn’t*, *shouldn’t*, &c.) arose in the 1700s, modelled after *won’t*. In modern English, *cannot* is the only uncontracted *-not* compound that survives.

As for the other contractions such as *-’ll* and *-’ve*, their history is just as long, though perhaps slightly less convoluted. But that’s a story for a different question. ;)

Also, remember that spelling in Old English was less standardised than in modern English. There were often several equally valid ways to spell the same word, especially when you took different accents and dialects into account. So sometimes it’s difficult to get a good historical account of pronunciation and usage changes. Still, as far as I can tell, this is basically how it went down.

Source: [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/).

Comment: +1 for great answer.  I think that "I want to go" and "I will go" do still mean something very similar, but many people now use "I will" and "I shall" interchangeably.  I'm sure I remember the following in a Jane Austen novel: "You will, but shall you?"  Not exactly modern, but not old-english either.

Comment: A minor quibble: _nawiht_ is surely "no what" or "no whit", not  "no way". _Nowt_ and _summat_ (< _somewhat_) are current where I live.

Comment: @ColinFine: Right, I was saying *not* meant *in no way*; it’s separate from but related to *nowt ~ no whit ~ na whit ~ nawiht ~ nan wiht*.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesperson%27s_cycle#Examples) says _not_ derives from _nawiht_. I haven't the books it references to hand, so I can't check whether or not it accurately reports them.

Comment: Correction: [Google books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OjtUmoQet5sC&pg=PA452&dq=kastovsky+English+syntax+nawiht&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1Ti7UJ31C4GK4AS6vYG4BQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kastovsky%20English%20syntax%20nawiht&f=false) has it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a contraction of *woll not*.

Comment: And what is 'woll' -- an old form of 'will'? Just curious.

Comment: @JAM: Yes, but there's rather more to it than that. If you're really interested, you'll need to read a history, preferably several histories, of the English language. It's not the sort of thing that's susceptible to a quick fix.

Comment: @JAM: this may elucidate matters further - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of

Comment: @Barrie England, can you suggest a history, preferably not too dry?

Comment: @JAM: You might try ‘The Oxford History of English’, edited by Lynda Mugglestone. For the origins of English, there’s no better introduction than ‘An Invitation to Old English and Anglo-Saxon England’ by Bruce Mitchell. The Oxford English Dictionary (subscription required) gives a detailed history of *will* in all its forms, running to some 500 lines.

Answer (score 4):

A friend found this [explanation of the etymology of "will"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=hYDQAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA375&ots=U39h_yVPcC&dq=will%20etymology%20wol&pg=PA375#v=onepage&q=will%20etymology%20wol&f=false) via Google Books. I found it interesting.

> Will is from the Gothic wilgan, Saxon willan, Dutch willen, German
>   wollen. Among the various writers cited, I find it written wil, wyl,
>   wyll, wrill, wol, woll. In Scotland it is often, to this day,
>   pronounced wull, and in some parts of England as if it were written
>   wool! The past tense was variously written when used as an auxiliary,
>   wold, wolde, wouldin, wulde, would. The German has present will,
>   imperfect wolte. Now, as wol and will seem originally to have been the
>   same in meaning, if not in every thing but spelling, and that
>   difference perhaps merely arising from ignorance or conforming to a
>   vicious pronunciation, it does not seem amiss to consider would as
>   derived from will; it certainly is derived from wol, and is as
>   certainly the past tense of will, the auxiliary, to which wol is
>   equivalent, and with which it was interchangeably used.

Answer (score 3):

It was fairly common to form the negative of a word by swapping the first letter (if a consonant) with an "n", or simply adding an "n" if the word started with a vowel.  Chaucer used the word *nas* to mean "ne was", or "was not".  *Nill* was the contraction of "ne will", whence *willy nilly* meaning "willing or unwilling" (or "like it or not").  *Nill* was driven out by *won't*.  There are many other examples that have survived — e.g., *naught* meaning "nothing" is the negative of *aught* meaning "anything of value".  *Neither* is the negative of *either*.

The same thing happened in other European languages.  *Willy nilly* in Latin is *volens nolens*.  *One* and *none* are *ullus* and *nullus*. In Afrikaans *iemand* is "somebody", and *niemand* is "nobody", *erens* means "somewhere", and *nerens* means "nowhere".

Answer (score 1):

Willn't is an archaic version that remains in some dictionaries.  I have no idea if it is in current use.  Once I found it as a teenager, I very, very occasionally used it as a bit of a joke.