# Why is "won't" allowed?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “won't” a contraction of?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of)

Why is it that we have "won't"? It makes no sense to me as there's no intuitive combination of two words such as "wouldn't".