# Why do we say won't instead of willn't?

Tags: contractions

If won't is the contraction of will not, where did the "wo" come from in won't? Why is this convention over willn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Won't* is a [contraction of "woll not"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of), *woll* being an old synonym (or alternative form) for *will*.

Why hasn't "willn't" (or "amn't" for that matter) become accepted?  I am tempted to attribute it to euphony, but that seems rather pat.