# Should "ya" have an apostrophe? "Doin"? Etc

Tags: punctuation, slang, abbreviations

"How ya doin?" v. "How ya' doin'?" and so on.

There's... a debate.

Comment: Certainly a matter of opinion, but I'd go with "How ya doin'?".

Comment: @HotLicks Why for "doing" and not "you"? Trying to nail down if there are any particular rules/norms for apostrophe application.

Comment: Just the way I usually see it, and the way it seems to me.  "Ya" is not considered an abbreviation, I suppose.

Comment: Feasibly some people might use **ya'** as a short form of **y'all** (i,e. - US "Deep South" speak for **you all**). But it's at the very least nonstandard. Come to that, **ya** itself isn't normally used either. It's a pointlessly distracting orthography that to my mind insults the intelligence of the reader (who's quite capable of inferring that **you** might be enunciated with a schwa instead of an 'oo' sound in many contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, actually all over the Southern US, not just 'Deep South', we say _y'all_. The only time _ya_ should be followed by an apostrophe is when it is part of the contraction of _ya_ and _will_: _ya'll_. I see people mistype this all the time, _ya'll_ when they meant to say _y'all_. Drives me nuts! ;)

Comment: It's nonstandard language and so doesn't really have a standard way of spelling ("y'all" notwithstanding). It looks more natural without the "'" to me. For debate's purposes, what letters is the "'" replacing (if it is intended to show a contraction)?

Comment: @Tim Ward: My scare quotes around "Deep South" were intended to acknowledge the fact that I'm sure there are plenty of Americans who would say they're from the ["Southern US"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_United_States), but reject the designation ["Deep South"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_South). As a Brit, I know little about such distinctions - to us, that latter term is mostly just a historical term relating to the time/place when/where supposedly civilised men kept other men as slaves.

Comment: Yes, @FumbleFingers, that was exactly my point. It isn't just an expression used by slavemasters in Mississippi. ;)

Comment: @Tim Ward: I know, but even though those slavemasters are [hopefully] all long dead now, I just can't resist any opportunity to stamp on their corpses. Particularly since I've just watched [*The Hateful Eight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3460252/?ref_=nv_sr_1), where Tarantino continues his long-established tradition of doing exactly the same.

Comment: (Even though unrelated, I would upvote your comment if I hadn't used all my upvotes for the day already, @FumbleFingers. I loved QT's _Django Unchained_! And I'm not a big Tarantino fan!)

Comment: If you like the *subject* more than the director, check out [Mandingo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073349/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) and [Pinky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041746/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). In some ways I find those even more "disturbing", because when they were being filmed there were still abominations like segregation (effectively, *apartheid*) in what was even then often thought of as the most "advanced" (certainly, most *powerful*) nation on earth. People are indeed strange.

Comment: If you're Joey on Friends, then you wouldn't because you make "you" flirtatiously rhyme with "do": "How you dooin'?"

Comment: Not really an answer, but without the apostrophe, "doin" looks like it rhymes with "loin" or "groin". Something out of Lord of the Rings: "Boin, son of Doin, of the great house of Goin!"

Comment: An apostrophe is for a missing letter, and nothing is missing in "ya" - it's just "you" mispelled. I'd say that no apostrophe is needed.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I use an apostrophe to indicate the place where letters have been omitted.

*What'll I do (**' = wi/sha**)*

*I'd say (' **= woul/shoul/coul**)*

*How ya doin' (' **= g**)*

***Ya*** is an alternative form of 'you' (- regional or colloq. = *you* pron.(OED))

Since there are no letters missing in 'ya' there is no apostrophe.

Comment: Is this codified somewhere I could refer to? I know that's the "rule" for most contractions/etc, I'm just wondering if it's similar for other constructs.

Comment: I thought *ya* was a contraction of *ya'll*, which was a contraction of *you all*. Hence, it should be *ya'*. But I might be mistaken. Your input is welcome. (Also, as a logician, I need to point out that you're wrong that you only use apostrophe to indicate letter omissions. I dare you to construct a possessive form without it. In a general case! *My* and *of crown* doesn't suffice...)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have a suspicion (but no evidence) that the apostrophe in the possessive suffix *is* indicating an omission, just one we've long forgotten. My amateur theory is based on modern German having a possessive (genitive) suffix "es", so "des Wortes Endung" -> *"the wordës ending" -> "the word's ending"...

Comment: @IMSoP It makes sense (as in, I can't contradict it without using google). In such case, Dan'll be able to prove me wrong by switching back a few centuries and schootching to a different language, hehe.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - thanks for reining in my extreme language.  I'm afraid I don't know if IMSoP is right or not about the possessive apostrophe, so  I've edited (PS. I don't get your last sentence).

Comment: Oh, I was just being nerdy nit-pick. One can technically speaking construct a genitive form without the apostrophe: "*it is **my** house.*" and "*defender **of** the Crown*", so I was just ass-covering my angles.

Comment: @IMSoP [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#History) still remembers: "The spelling **-es** remained, but in many words the letter **-e-** no longer represented a sound. In those words, printers often copied the French practice of substituting an apostrophe for the letter **e**. In later use, **-'s** was used for all nouns where the /s/ sound was used for the possessive form, and when adding **-'s** to a word like **love** the **e** was no longer omitted."

Comment: When "ya" means "you" there aren't any letters missing, but I think an argument could be made for "How 'ya doin'", on the basis that it's a further contraction of how're ya, pronounced slightly differently from e.g. "I don't know how ya do this".

Comment: @supercat - Agreed.  I'd write that as *How'ya doin'*.

Comment: Note that the "yall" contraction is actually spelled _"y'all"_, rather than "ya'll"

Comment: @Dan: I'd be inclined to put in a space, since the point of contraction includes a word break [one wouldn't write "whether'tis  better to ...", for example], but would consider either form, or the one without the apostrophe, reasonable.  Different people pronounce the construct differently, and since the reason for writing anything involving "ya" is to reflect pronunciation, using different orthography for different pronunciations would seem appropriate.

Comment: @supercat - So you would write ***How ' ya doin'***?

Comment: @Dan: I'd attach the apostrophe to `'ya`; see my answer.

Comment: @supercat - the problem with that is that the missing letters (word, in fact - *are*)  belong neither to 'how' nor 'ya'.

Answer (score 19):

It doesn't make sense to put an apostrophe after "ya", because no letters have been omitted. And that's what apostrophe indicates — it isn't a general clue that a word is shortened in some way.

In "ya", the "ou" vowel has been replaced with "a". We don't have punctuation to indicate that, so we just write it.

This is also generally the case where a replacement slang/informal word *is* missing letters, but others have changed. When this happens, we usually just transcribe the sounds rather than using an apostrophe. For example, we write "gimme" for the hurried expression which means "give me". We don't write "gi'me", even though that might make logical sense. And, we write "gonna" for "going to", rather than....  "go'na", I guess. (Yeah, not that.)

Comment: Interestingly it seems people did use to write '*gi'me*'.  I guess, over time the familiar version - *gimme* - took over.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=gimme%2Cgi+'+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share="

Comment: And, I guess "[won't](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/what-is-wont-a-contraction-of)" might be an exception to the general rule I'm giving here. But, it wouldn't be English if we didn't have a few of those. :)

Comment: Well, also, the spelling *gi'me* doesn't represent the short i, so it looks like you want to add another m.   And there seems to be an unwritten convention that in general once you add or change some letters, that trumps the apostrophizing to some degree and you just opt for a direct transcription of the sound.    Examples: your *gonna* example, *kinda* not *kinda'*, *watcha*, *wanna* not *wan'a*, *lemme* not *le'me*.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Hm. How about "kind'f" or "kind've" then? That's one aspect I hadn't thought've.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I feel like "kind've" is the same as "kind of". I'm not capable of saying the former without introducing the same "uv" sound we normally use to pronounce "of". And unlike "c'mon", we aren't changing the emphasis or pronunciation, just the speed. I could understand "I'mkindofinahurry" if you were trying to emphasize someone speaking quickly, or "kindof" to do the same.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - 'Kind of' is a funny one.  Because the 'f' is pronounced like a 'v' the 'correct' short version, *kind'f*, seems wrong.  On the other hand, *Kind'v* seems laboured (and risks being interpreted as 'kind have').  Which leaves *kinda* or *kin(e)duv*!

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere, you're informal and/or in a hurry so adding apostrophes on proper places defeats the purpose in my opinion (unless there's some other purpose like writing a book or something).

disclaimer: now I'm not native speaker and this is not an advice about grammatical correctness

Comment: Normally one wouldn't write like this to save time (that'd be "how u doin" or somesuch). One would write this way to reflect a speaker's dialect and/or informal tone.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that at least in some dialects, the phrase "are you" is (informally) spoken as something between "ee-ah" and "eh-ya", which is distinct from "ya" meaning "you"; I would suggest `'ya` (with the apostrophe) as an orthography for shortened form of "are you", since any other notation for that initial vowel sound would be apt to cause confusion.  In many cases, context would distinguish between the usages even without a difference in spelling, but I would regard the following as different questions, with somewhat different pronunciations:

- 'Ya lost?
- Ya lost?

The former question would be asking whether someone *is* confused about their location; the latter would ask whether they had been vanquished.

I would thus notate the question `How 'ya doin'` with the apostrophe as shown, pronounced as "Howie adieuing"; if `ya` were used to simply mean "you", as in "I don't know how ya do it", I would omit the apostrophe.

Comment: Interesting distinction; I'm not sure about the apostrophe in the first case. The more I think about it the less I know. Ya know?

Comment: @DaveNewton: English orthography often necessitates compromises when transcribing dialect.  The first syllable of "`ya`" can replace a variety of linking verbs including "do", and in many questions the word "do" is grammatically optional but affects meaning *slightly*, so `Ya know?` or `'Ya know?` would both work [though they are pronounced differently].  Note that the "ee-ah" pronunciation doesn't work in places where no linking verb would fit, e.g. with past-tense verb forms which can't be used as participles like `Ya broke it`.